# How to use query string in cake php

Tags: url, cakephp

I am new in cake php

I made an application in cake php i want to use query string (no exactly query string )some what like this

http://example.net/meditations/index/mins/2

How i can get number 2 (at the end of this above url )

I want this number from url to  inside "meditation" controller "index" function.

How I can get that value ?

Thanks

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action**

Comment: Also read [passed-named-or-query-string-params](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/). You seem to confusing quite a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Link Name', array('controller' => 'meditations', 'action' => 'index', 'mins', 2));?>
```

Answer (score -3):

You could also do it like below:

http://example.net/meditations/index/?mins=2

Then in your meditations controller index action fetch the value of mins like this:

$_REQUEST['mins']